# Remove certain letters from input string

Tags: c#, string, replace

I'm currently having a problem where when I search for a code I want to remove the any "."'s a user has inputted. The code I've done doesn't seem to be working and was wondering if someone could tell me why and what I need to do. Thanks.

```
foreach (var letters in id)
{
    string letter = letters.ToString();
    if (letter == ".")
    {
        id.Replace(letter, "");
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to go through string characters to replace a specific one, replace does it for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/362314fe.aspx) in .NET is an immutable type, therefore you can't change the value of an existing `string` variable, you need to replace it entirely with the value returned by [Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx) i.e.

```
id = id.Replace(letter, "");
```

FYI you don't have to check whether `.` is contained in the string, you can just call `Replace(".", "")` on the resultant string and it will remove any `.` present i.e.

```
id = id.Replace(".", "");
```

[See example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/e58sbA)

Answer (score 0):

[String replace method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
id = id.Replace(",", "");
```

Answer (score -1):

Programmaticaly, maybe you can use that besides Replace() method

```
  string m_tempStr = "This.is.a.test";
    List<string> myList = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < m_tempStr.Length; i++)
    {
        if (m_tempStr[i].ToString() != ".")
        {
            myList.Add(m_tempStr[i].ToString());
        }
    }
```

And than, you can get each member of list like following sample code

```
    foreach (var item in myList)
    {
        Console.Write(item);
    }
```